# Cannot scroll to bottom of ScrollView in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I have a very simple example of using a `ScrollView` and I cannot seem to scroll to the bottom.

The example is completely basic, I'm not doing anything special yet the last item is never fully visible.

[Expo Code](https://repl.it/J4Wr/1)

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { Text, View, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
 import { Constants } from "expo";

 const data = Array.from({ length: 20 }).map((_, i) => i + 1);

 export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            {data.map(d => (
                <View style={styles.view}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{d}</Text>
                </View>
            ))}
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
     paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
  },
  text: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#fff",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 28
},
view: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#018bbc"
  }
 });
```

Here is the output:

[image: output image]

Comment: adding `flex: 1` to the container should do the trick

Comment: @AakashSigdel I have a similar use case. `flex: 1` did not work. I'm still mucking around with various props, but so far whenever I scroll to the bottom, the view bounces back up preventing me from selecting the last item, which happens to be a button.

Comment: you should change the correct answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify your `render()` method and wrap the `ScrollView` inside a `View` container, and set the `paddingTop` to that `View` container:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={ styles.container}>
            <ScrollView >
                {data.map(d => <View style={styles.view}><Text style={styles.text}>{d}</Text></View>)}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: At first, this appears logical. I implemented it in my code, however, with no apparent effect. I have a button at the bottom of my `ScrollView` that is unreachable because the view bounces back to the top after the tap is released. I expect the scroll to stay put when the view is released.

Comment: Just adding a `View` around the `ScrollView` did the trick for me: `<View><ScrollView>{ this.renderStuff }</ScrollView></View>`

Answer (score 95):

Apply padding styles to "contentContainerStyle" prop instead of "style" prop of the ScrollView.

Comment: To anyone wondering why this works: stackoverflow.com/a/52894044/16492542

Answer (score 42):

I had just a `ScrollView` in my application and it was working fine. Then I added a header component at the top, and the bottom of my `ScrollView` was not visible any more. I tried everything and nothing worked. Until I found a solution after an hour of trying every crazy thing and here it is. I fixed the issue by adding `paddingBottom` as `contentContainerStyle` to my `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 60}} >
    {this.renderItems()}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This seems to be extremely effective. Have you ran into any issues with it over time?

Comment: Fortunately, not yet. :)

Answer (score 12):

set `flexGrow: 1` to `contentContainerStyle` of your `ScrollView`

```
contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
```

Answer (score 9):

I fixed mine by setting Scrollview's `contentInset` bottom property to a value just enough for me to see bottommost part of my content (a button in my case).

Example:

```js
<ScrollView
  contentInset={{bottom: 80}}>
  {{ content }}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is what I needed. My scrollview is inside a modal and uses contentContainerStyle for its styles, but none of them really helped. Except this. Thanks!

Comment: Bare in mind that this is applicable to iOS only. [Source](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#contentinset-ios)

Answer (score 4):

I have this issue and fixed it. To solve it:
flex:1 means “expand it to its parent size”, if parent have a 0 height, it won’t work
flex:-1 means “shrink it to fit its children size”, if child height set to flex:1 (depends on parent) -> it wont’ work -> you ask me? I ask you back. loop.
scrollview have two view in it -> a `{flex:1}` outer view wrapped a `{flex:-1}` inner view. when inner view taller than outer view, that’s when scroll happen.
It also means outer view height depends on scrollview parent, inner view depends on children. If you cannot give a height to its outer view, the outer view will become 0 height. You cannot scroll inner view with a 0 height outer view, it will always bounce back to it origin position once your finger release.
wrap it with a `<View style={{flex:1}}>` may or may not solve your problems because it means the scrollview’s parent expand itself to fit its parent,height then depends on it parent. (the grand parent of your scrollview). So if your grand parent have no height defined, it fail.

The follow example won’t works

```
<View style={{height:300,width:200}}>
<View> //<-this break
<View {{flex:1}}>
<ScrollView>{contents}</ScrollView>
</View>
</View>
</View>
```

and this work:

```
 var {Windowheight, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
<View style={{height:Windowheight}}>
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<ScrollView>{contents}</ScrollView>
<View>
</View>
```

this also work:

```
 var {windowHeight, windowWidth} = Dimensions.get('window');
<View style={{height:windowHeight}}>
<Toolbar or other component with fixed height>
<ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>{contents}</ScrollView>
<Footer or other component with fixed height>
</View>
```

Conclusion, make sure your scrollview height determinable both from outside and inside. If weird things happen trace the ancestor until you find a height or simply define a solid one within its traceable ancestor without rely on flex:1 Some third party component wrap things with a `<View>` which breaks things.

Comment: Thank you! You finally explained to me how ScrollView actually works. After reading your comment I was able to fix my ScrollView within 5 minutes, literally.

Answer (score 4):

Added height style for ScrollView.

```
height:'100%', width:'100%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the child components height without using % e.g make `minHeight: '10%'` -> `minHeight: 10`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).